# How do I avoid reconnecting to the database with every REST-request send by a client-application?

Tags: php, database, rest

I am currently writing a simple `RESTful` web-application (with PHP), but I am not sure how to efficiently handle database access. The problem is that creating a connection to my MySQL database is quite time consuming.

My first idea was to create a Singleton as a Database Management object, which only connects to the database when the connection hasn't been setup already.
However, my connection object is always null because I guess with every request made by the client, the php script files are reloaded on the server. Hence, with every request that needs to access the database, the connection has to be initialised.

Is there a design pattern or technique that I could use to avoid this problem?

Comment: This is a good answer, IMO. Anyway, I think there is no such a design pattern nor technique solving this. You could try using persistent connection - this could help a bit. The other way is to solve why the connection is so much time consuming and trying to lower this time...

Comment: There's always persistent connections

Comment: A bit off-topic, but have you considered storing commonly used data in a memory cache? (Such as [APC](http://php.net/apc)?)

Comment: Setting up one connection does not take that long, but I think it will add up... Persistent connections seem to be a good idea. @ middaparka: I am not completely sure how caches work... Would I be able to save the connection object in cache and would it remain there even if the script has terminated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Persistent Database Connections](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php):

> Persistent connections are good if the overhead to create a link to
> your SQL server is high. Whether or not this overhead is really high
> depends on many factors. Like, what kind of database it is, whether or
> not it sits on the same computer on which your web server sits, how
> loaded the machine the SQL server sits on is and so forth. The bottom
> line is that if that connection overhead is high, persistent
> connections help you considerably. They cause the child process to
> simply connect only once for its entire lifespan, instead of every
> time it processes a page that requires connecting to the SQL server.
> This means that for every child that opened a persistent connection
> will have its own open persistent connection to the server. For
> example, if you had 20 different child processes that ran a script
> that made a persistent connection to your SQL server, you'd have 20
> different connections to the SQL server, one from each child.

Here's the [mysql_pconnect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php) documentation page.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a good solution.
So if I had one class that acts as an interface to the database, so this class would be the only one creating a connection to the SQL server, then I would only have one connection to the database no matter how many people use the service or did I get that wrong?